Google Slides Presentation Mode w/ Start Chromium_Script
I'm trying to set up some signage at my business. I've used a start_chromium.sh script with other things and it has worked, but for whatever reason, when I try using it with Google Slide, it does not work. In Google Slides, I go to Publish to Web, set the timing, then copy the link to my script. When I start the Pi, it opens the presentation in 5 different tabs and ignores the timing settings I entered. This does not happen if I just copy it into another tab on my own PC. Wondering if anyone has had any experience using Google Slide with Start Chromium.

The URL you're using from Google Slides should be correctly formatted. It should look something like this: https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/e/2PACX-1vQ0B2_example_7GdySg/pub?start=true&loop=true&delayms=3000. Verify that the parameters for starting the presentation and the timing are correct.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Update:
I was able to get the Pi to boot and open the presentation, but I've run into a new issue. If I make a change to the slideshow and then reboot the Pi, it does not open the slides. It just opens a normal Chromium tab.

I’m voting to close this question because it may be the furthest off-topic question I've seen posted here.
